# How to check if my graphics card (driver) is working properly? [Debian 9]

Tags: debian, drivers, nvidia, benchmark, graphic-card

I have a nvidia graphics card and for getting it to work I only added `contrib non-free` to my repositories' sections in synaptic <sup>(reluctantly)</sup>, installed `nvidia-driver` and restarted.

In the `NVIDIA X Server Settings` everything looks fine and it displays the correct graphics card model. However I'm not sure if I also need to install some "headers" or install/configure any additional things? If it's possible that I may need some kernel headers is there some tool that allows me to check if so and which ones? And can I install them after installing the nvidia-driver?

What's the best way to check if my graphics card is working properly and able to make use of its performance-potential? Some benchmark test I guess?